# Robotframework installation - keyword not found error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, test-automation-framework, robotframework

I have set up [robotframework](https://robotframework.org) on my machine and I have installed all necessary plugin and using Pycharm as IDE.

But I am getting `keyword not found` error and also SeleniumLibrary library which I have defined in the setting section is giving me inspection info: `This inspection occurs when library or resources is not defined`.

Please go through attached screenshot for more details.

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: pip install --upgrade robotframework-seleniumlibrary did you install the library?

Comment: Just see your Library - This is in small char "seleniumlibrary" . you should just make it like
SeleniumLibrary
Just try it before copying someones code you will learn something

Comment: Check the code on the screenshot it is written as SeleniumLibrary.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined any test cases, so RF interprets `Open Browser` as the test case name and `gc` as a keyword.

A .robot file is not a single test case but a collection of test cases, a suite.

```
*** Settings ***
Library        SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${url}        https//www.happyeasygo.com/

*** Test Cases ***
My Test Case
    Open Browser    ${url}    gc

My 2nd Test Case
    Log    This is my second test case
```

Answer (score 1):

In the test case table, the first column/cell represents the test case name, and then the next column is either blank, a variable, or a keyword.

Thus, in your example `Open browser` is considered the test case name, `${url}` is a variable to be assigned, and `gc` is considered to be a keyword.

If you want to call `open browser`, it needs to be indented under a test case name. For example:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    Open browser  ${url}  gc
```